# React TypeError when creating custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I have following hook

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useKeycloak} from "@react-keycloak/web";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export const useAdminApi = () => {

    const {keycloak} = useKeycloak();
    const [axiosInstance, setAxiosInstance] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        let instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_ADMIN_API_URL}`,
            headers: {
                Test: 'test',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token,
            }
        });

        setAxiosInstance(instance);

        return () => {
            setAxiosInstance(undefined);
        }
    }, [keycloak.token]);

    const getUsers = ({query}) => {
        return axiosInstance.get(`/users${query}`)
    };

    const getUserDetail = ({userId}) => {
        return axiosInstance.get(`/users/${userId}`)
    };

    const deleteUser = ({userId}) => {
        return axiosInstance.delete(`/users/${userId}`)
    };


    return {
        getUsers,
        getUserDetail,
        deleteUser
    }
};
```

When I log `instance` it's logged with all config

From `useAdminApi` I'd like to export functions like `getUserDetail`, `deleteUser`, ...

Then in other component, I'd like to use this functions so I have following:

```
const UserForm = () => {
    const {getUserDetail} = useAdminApi();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!userId) {
            setIsNew(true);
        } else {
            setIsNew(false);
            getUserDetail({userId})
                .then(result => setUserData(result.data))
                .catch(error => pushError(push, error));
        }
    }, [userId]);

   ...
}
```

However, when I display the `UserForm` I'm getting following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` which is pointing to this line `` return axiosInstance.get(`/users/${userId}`) ``

Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `axiosInstance`'s initial value as `undefined` but TypeScript doesn't infer the type you want. `useState` is a generic function, so what you can do is pass the type yourself.

```js
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
```

```js
const [axiosInstance, setAxiosInstance] = useState<AxiosInstance | undefined>(
  undefined
);
```

Then in your functions you still need to check if `axiosInstance` is `undefined`.

If you have TypeScript 3.7 or higher you can achieve this with Optional Chaining.

```js
const getUsers = ({ query }: any) => {
  return axiosInstance?.get(`/users${query}`);
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response but I'm not using typescript. It's just ES6.

Comment: You're correct, and I was wondering why didn't this line get an error then. `setAxiosInstance(instance);` Just wrap your `return` with an `if`.  `if (axiosInstance) { ... }`

Comment: well yes, in that case it doesn't fail, but it doesn't return what I want. I just want to resolve the original issue. And that is why the axiosInstance isn't propagated outside of hook :(

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this locally. When I create the instance it's firing a request to `baseURL`. I managed to get this to work by setting the state as a function that returns the instance. `setAxiosInstance(() => instance);`